# Is there a way to add positives and negatives with the same algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

It is taught to us in grade school that you can add (positive) numbers like this:

```
    5 2 3
    4 5 6
   -------
    5 7 9
```

But if we change it to `523 + (-456)`, we cannot use the same algorithm

```
    5  2  3
   -4 -5 -6  
   ---------
    1 -3 -3
```

I know that I can evaluate that to `100 + -(30) + (-3)` which gets `67`, but in my situation, 17 is the maximum integer, and -17 is the minimum integer (excluding the actual numbers being added). Is there a way to do this where the `523 + 456` also works?

Comment: "but in my situation, 17 is the maximum integer, and -17 is the minimum integer (excluding the actual numbers being added)"  What does that mean? Where did $17$ come from.  Why are the maximum and minimum and why is it a problem.  It seems like you *have* come up with an algorithm that *does* work for all four cases.  I don't think you have an issue.

Comment: 17 is the maximum integer because 9 * 2 - 1 = 17. The maximum integer in my case is determined by (the base (10) - 1) * 2 - 1.

Comment: The maximum integer for what?  ANd why is that an issue?  Just do what you did.  It works.  So what if you get $17$ or $-17$.  (BTW why isn't the maximum $18$?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I am doing this for a programming project, and in my actual case 2 ^ 63 - 1 is the real maximum integer for my project (because of the maximum `long long` in c++), but for this question I changed the 2 ^ 63 - 1, to 17.

Comment: Long subtraction is similar to long addition, but you carry $-1$ instead of $+1$, that's all. `for (int i=0,x=0;i<N;++i) {x+=(a[i]-b[i]);c[i]=x%d;x/=d;}`

Comment: what are `d`, `x`, and `c` in that loop?

Comment: Why don't you actually *ask* the question you  have in mind?  Trying to put it in simpler terms leaving us to have to guess what you *really* want and asking a completely different question *doesn't* make things easy.

Comment: The question I asked was my real question. I was going to take the concept given by an answer and convert that into code that performs the task I assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `long long` data type in c++ represents numbers range from $\ -2^{63}\ $ to $\ 2^{63}-1\ $ is because the representation used is $64$-bit [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).  An analogous representations in decimal would be $n$-digit "tens complement", for some $\ n\ $, which could represent all the numbers in the range $\ -\frac{10^n}{2}\ $ to $\ \frac{10^n}{2}-1\ $, so it's not at all clear (not, at lest, to me) where your "maximum integer" of $17$ comes from, or what it is meant to be the maximum of.

Nevertheless, if you represent decimal numbers using sequences of positive and negative digits from $-9$ to $9$, as you have done, you can convert any representation to any equivalent one without needing to use any numbers outside the range $-9$ to $9$.

In your example, $\ 1\ -3\ -3\ $, for instance, first replace the rightmost digit by $7$ and decrease the next digit to the left by $1$ to get the equivalent representation $\ 1\ -4\ \ 7\ $.  You don't even need to get the $7$ by subtracting $3$ from $10$, since you can get it by subtracting one less than $3$, namely $2$, from $9$.

Next, replace the new middle digit, $-4$, with $6$, and decrease the leftmost digit by $1$ to get the equivalent representation $\ 0\ 6\ 7\ $, from which the new leftmost digit $0$ can be deleted to give you $67$.

Comment: So, for each negative digit, get the complement from 10 and subtract the right digit by 1?

Comment: Yes, except that it's the digit to the *left* of the one you complement that you need to decrease by $1$, not the one to its right, That doesn't change the number represented because you've increased the number represented by the first digit by $10$ (or by $10^n$ if it's in the $n^\text{th}$ position from the right, and decreased the number represented by the digit on its left by the same amount.